# How can I correct my war application (Tomcat 8)?

Tags: tomcat, jsf, primefaces, war

I made a Web Java Application, on `JDK 1.8`, with the next libraries:

```
 - Hibernate 4.3.x
 - bootstrap 1.0.10
 - commons codec 1.10
 - commons logging 1.2
 - poi 3.12-20150511
 - poi ooxml 3.12-20150511
 - poi ooxml-schemas 3.12-20150511
 - xmlbeans 2.6.0
 - gson 2.3.1
 - bson4jackson 2.7.0
 - jackson annotations 2.7.3
 - jackson core 2.7.3
 - jackson databind 2.7.3
 - jongo 1.3.0
 - mongo java driver 3.2.2
 - postgresql 9.4.1208jre6
 - primefaces 6.0
 - commons fileupload 1.3.1
 - commons io 2.4
```

I developed my application on Netbeans 8.0 and finally I generated a war file. After I downloaded and installed `Tomcat 8` in my computer (with `Windows 8.1` to 64 bits) to 32 bits, and when I mount my war file on Tomcat, and I accessed to `http://localhost:8080/MyApplication` the page respond with `HTTP STATUS 404` message.

As I don't know what is the file with the specific exception, I show all the files of the log folder:

catalina.2017-03-20.log

```
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.589 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.12
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.616 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 8 2017 17:41:47 UTC
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.637 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.12.0
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.660 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 8.1
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.661 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.3
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.662 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.662 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.663 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.663 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.663 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.664 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.665 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.665 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.666 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.666 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.666 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\logging.properties
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.667 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.667 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.667 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.667 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin;C:\tas-8.3-1\multiserver\enhydra\bin; C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;;.
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.005 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.593 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.599 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.605 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.606 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2024 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.680 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Arrancando servicio Catalina
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.680 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.12
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.761 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Despliegue del archivo C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\MyApplication.war de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.612 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyApplication]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: El mapeo de filtro especifica un nombre desconocido de filtro PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2987)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2950)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1275)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1190)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5114)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.615 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error durante el despliegue del archivo C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\MyApplication.war de la aplicación web
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyApplication]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.621 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\MyApplication.war has finished in 16.856 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.625 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.899 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs has finished in 274 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.900 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\examples de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.762 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\examples has finished in 862 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.762 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\host-manager de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.833 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\host-manager has finished in 71 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.834 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.954 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager has finished in 120 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.955 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.999 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT has finished in 44 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:17.008 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8081]
20-Mar-2017 19:32:17.047 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
20-Mar-2017 19:32:17.054 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 18447 ms
```

commons-daemon.2017-03-20.log

```
[2017-03-20 19:31:55] [info]  [ 1908] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 32-bit) started
[2017-03-20 19:31:55] [info]  [ 1908] Running 'Tomcat8' Service...
[2017-03-20 19:31:55] [info]  [ 4584] Starting service...
[2017-03-20 19:31:57] [info]  [ 4584] Service started in 1292 ms.
```

host-manager.2017-03-20.log

```
[is empty]
```

localhost.2017-03-20.log

```
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.740 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.741 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

localhost_access_log.2017-03-20.txt

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Mar/2017:19:32:27 -0500] "GET /MyApplication/ HTTP/1.1" 404 994
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Mar/2017:19:32:29 -0500] "GET /MyApplication/ HTTP/1.1" 404 994
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Mar/2017:19:32:29 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Mar/2017:19:32:30 -0500] "GET /MyApplication/ HTTP/1.1" 404 994
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [20/Mar/2017:19:32:30 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
```

manager.2017-03-20.log

```
[Is empty]
```

tomcat8-stderr.2017-03-20.log

```
2017-03-20 19:31:55 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.589 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.12
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.616 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 8 2017 17:41:47 UTC
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.637 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.12.0
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.660 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 8.1
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.661 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.3
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.662 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.662 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.663 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.663 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.663 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.664 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.665 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.665 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.666 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.666 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.666 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\logging.properties
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.667 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.667 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.667 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
20-Mar-2017 19:31:57.667 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin;C:\tas-8.3-1\multiserver\enhydra\bin; C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;;.
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.005 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.593 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.599 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.605 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.606 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2024 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.680 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Arrancando servicio Catalina
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.680 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.12
20-Mar-2017 19:31:58.761 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Despliegue del archivo C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\MyApplication.war de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.612 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyApplication]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: El mapeo de filtro especifica un nombre desconocido de filtro PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2987)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2950)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1275)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1190)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5114)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.615 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error durante el despliegue del archivo C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\MyApplication.war de la aplicación web
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyApplication]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.621 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\MyApplication.war has finished in 16.856 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.625 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.899 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs has finished in 274 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:15.900 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\examples de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.762 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\examples has finished in 862 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.762 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\host-manager de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.833 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\host-manager has finished in 71 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.834 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.954 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager has finished in 120 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.955 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT de la aplicación web
20-Mar-2017 19:32:16.999 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT has finished in 44 ms
20-Mar-2017 19:32:17.008 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8081]
20-Mar-2017 19:32:17.047 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
20-Mar-2017 19:32:17.054 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 18447 ms
```

tomcat8-stdout.2017-03-20.log

```
2017-03-20 19:31:55 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
```

And the `web.xml` of my application is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tsp.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ttf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff2</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-woff2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-eot</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            -1
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Could you help me to understand and solve the error?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Your problem is right under the exception stack `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: El mapeo de filtro especifica un nombre desconocido de filtro PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter`. That means you have use an invalid or an inexistent filter on your (most probably) web.xml file. You need to show it. You can edit your question removing all logs but `catalina.2017-03-20.log` since it's the only one needed here...

Comment: Yes Jorge, thanks, but I remove this refference on my web.xml

Comment: You should use it like this guy on his question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359033/jsf-configuration-of-the-file-upload-filter